# Is there a way for screen saver to always lock my computer screen?

Tags: screensaver

So basically my screen saver is an important security feature.

If I am away from my computer I want to make sure people need to logged in first before accessing my computer. I want to make sure that my computer is automatically locked out after I am away for a few minutes.

Somehow it doesn't work that way.

After 30 minutes or so my computer is still logged in.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? Provide screenshots of your screensaver settings? Is this machine connected to an AD domain? Have you set the group policies responsible for your desired behavior[?](https://superuser.com/questions/439340/screensaver-group-policy-not-working?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which version of Windows you are using, but I'll put the instructions for Windows 11, on older version it's similar but not exactly the same way to get to this window.)

- Go to ***Settings*** > ***Personalization*** > ***Lock screen***, and
  select **Screen saver** under *Related Settings*
- In the ***Screen Saver Settings*** window, place a check by **On resume, display logon screen**
- Click **OK** to save

[image]

Comment: Also, there is a *grace period* from the time the lock screen is shown until a password is needed to unlock the PC. That key in the Registry is at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`, and the value is `ScreenSaverGracePeriod`. If set too long, it would delay locking unduly. Set it to your convnenience.